# Is it possible to connect ATMEGA328 to type-C and read data without a USB-TTL converter?

Tags: arduino, atmega, ttl

there was a task to create the most compact device with `atmega328` on board, but the question arose whether it could read data from type-c without a ttl converter like `ch340g` and `atmega16u2`, is it possible?

Comment: would be easier to get a devboard with a USB-C socket built-in, like most ESP32S3 and some 32S2/32C3 boards have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mega328 does not have an USB interface.

It is still technicaly possible to use software bit-banged VUSB interface with it, but it's a trick and will only allow very low speed communication at high CPU usage, complex code, and unorthodox hardware usage that either requires overclocking/undervolting the AVR to out of specs or USB connections to PC that if done incorrectly may damage the PC USB port.

So, while technically possible, I cannot recommend using the VUSB method due to abovementioned issues it being a trick, so I will say I specifically recommend not to use VUSB method so in practice it is not possible.

Having said that, if you want USB connectivity, simply buy a better MCU with USB interface. I believe there are cheaper faster 32-bit ARM MCUs with USB and more memory that what the Mega328P offers.

Answer (score 2):

Atmega328 does not have a hardware USB implementation, so you should better use something like atmega32u4 or atmega16u2. But, you can use a software implementation of a low-speed USB protocol, [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html). Keep in mind that it can, and will eat up your flash memory and processor time easily.

Comment: (Immediately after upvoting I got 2nd thoughts about suggesting a 16u2 when the question asks *without a ttl converter like ch340g and atmega16u2*.)

Comment: @greybeard Atmega16u2 is NOT a ttl converter, I think the author is a bit confused.

Comment: @sx107 It actually is. Just like any other USB UART chip, they all are just microcontrollers running a program to communicate with UART on one end and looking like a USB CDC/ACM serial port on the other end. For example the Mega16U has been used as a USB serial interface in place of CH340 on some Arduino boards.